# Multilanguage Website Php

Tags: php, session, multilingual, lang

When I go from default language to other language everything works okay but, them when I try to go to different page on chosen language (example. from home to contact) it brings me back to default language. I guess that it's got something to do with sessions?

```
session_start();
$available_langs = array('en','fr','de');
$_SESSION['lang'] = 'en'; 
if(isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] != ''){ 
    if(in_array($_GET['lang'], $available_langs))
    {       
      $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang']; 
    }
}
include('languages/'.$_SESSION['lang'].'/lang.'.$_SESSION['lang'].'.php');
```

Comment: you are setting the language every time you load a different page, not just, when the language is not set. e.g. try to change `$_SESSION['lang'] = isset($_SESSION['lang']) ? $_SESSION['lang'] : 'en';`

Comment: My vote is that you use cookies instead. Typically you only need to use Session data for private information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution - Cookies. Everything is working great now.